# HMAC secret key length and Node's crypto library

Tags: node.js, cryptography, jwt

I'm trying to use HMAC SHA256 for JWT. I've read that I should have 256 bits in my key. However, Node's `crypto` library accepts a string as a key. Does it convert each character to its unicode number? If I just use single-byte utf8 characters, will 32 characters create a 256-bit key (256/8=32)? Since Javascript uses utf8 strings and utf8 pads each byte with a `0`, won't there be a `0` every 8th bit?

How do I ensure that my secret key has 256 bits?

Here's what I have:

```
let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', SECRET);
hmac.update(payload);
let signature = toUrlSafe(hmac.digest('base64'));
```

Comment: If you're unsure, then just use a `Buffer` instead of a "binary string", which all functions accept.